# Trying to recover a NTFS corrupt partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, ntfs, filesystem-corruption

I'm stucked with the fixing of a NTFS partition, which I kind of recovered from the MFT backup using *TestDisk 7.2-WIP* on Windows 7, even so the partition recovered is corrupted.

[image]

[image]

Applying on Debian Linux the instructions of  https://www.andreafortuna.org/dfir/how-to-extract-data-and-timeline-from-master-file-table-on-ntfs-filesystem/ to analyze the **Master File Table** (with *analyzeMFT.py*) I can get the partition layout of the hard drive:

```
debian:~# mmls /dev/sdc
DOS Partition Table
Offset Sector: 0
Units are in 512-byte sectors

      Slot      Start        End          Length       Description
000:  Meta      0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   Primary Table (#0)
001:  -------   0000000000   0000016063   0000016064   Unallocated
002:  Meta      0000000063   0976773119   0976773057   Win95 Extended (0x0f)
003:  Meta      0000000063   0000000063   0000000001   Extended Table (#1)
004:  001:000   0000016064   0976768064   0976752001   NTFS / exFAT (0x07)
005:  -------   0976768065   0976773167   0000005103   Unallocated
```

I'm interested in the **NTFS / exFAT (0x07)** partition, starting in the offset of *16064*
But instead of displaying the content of that inode, it shows an error:

```
debian:~# icat -o 16064 /dev/sdc 0 > mft.raw
Cannot determine file system type
```

Specifying the file system is futile...

```
debian:~# icat -f ntfs -o 16064 /dev/sdc 0 > mft.raw
Invalid magic value (Not a NTFS file system (magic))
```

... not even as a **RAW** filesystem:

```
debian:~# icat -f raw -o 16064 /dev/sdc 0 > mft.raw
Function/Feature not supported (Illegal analysis method for raw data )
```

Even *fdisk* says it's a **NTFS** filesystem:

```
debian:~# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: 00LPVX-22V0TT0  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa5eb893d

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          63 976773119 976773057 465.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdc5       16064 976768064 976752001 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

*ntfsfix* finally provides some insight into the problem:

```
debian:~# ntfsfix /dev/sdc5
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

But I was twice wrong, *chkdsk* can't even work with the filesystem, it says it's a **RAW** filesystem:

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk d: /f
The type of the file system is RAW. 
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

The question is: How to set the filesystem type as NTFS without formatting the partition?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112534/discussion-on-question-by-abiyi-trying-to-recover-a-ntfs-corrupt-partition).